# C# unchecked keyword in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I use linq aggregate() with possible Int32 overflow:

```
items.Aggregate(0, (acc, item) => { unchecked { return acc * 10000 + item.Id; } });
```

Is there any way to simplify expression?

Like async e.g.:

```
async () => {}
```

Comment: OK, valid question, but what does this have to do with async?

Comment: @usr async is just example without redundant braces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get rid of the `{}` and the `return` statement:

```
items.Aggregate(0, (acc, item) => unchecked (acc * 10000 + item.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, I've done some tests... This works:

```
unchecked 
{
    int res = items.Aggregate(0, (acc, item) => acc * 10000 + item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

(the test app I created is `checked`, so if I remove the `unchecked`, I get an `OverflowException`)